# How to fix ssl error code 2633 error in python

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I tried to install kivy use pip. And always it gave me this error.

pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:2633)

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Before I used 3.9 and now using 3.8. But same result.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, try to reopen the terminal.
If the issue still there, try to restart your PC and restart your router.